# SDWebImage not setting images in UITableView cells until scroll in Xcode 9.0 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have been using SDWebImage in one of my projects for quite long and accidentally happened to open the project up in the recently released Xcode 9.0 beta. The library was working absolutely fine on the previous versions so I can't help but think it's Xcode that's broken it.

The issue I am facing is that the images in `UITableView` do not get set when the cells are initially loaded. The images are set only when scrolled out of the view and then back in. I have tried setting placeholder images but to no use. Any help would be very much appreciated. I have been banging my head over this for quite a while now and can't find any solutions.

Comment: Have a look at this link https://teamtreehouse.com/community/images-not-showing-after-xcode-and-ios-9-update

Comment: Security doesn't seem to be an issue @Malik as it's the UIImageViews in UITableViewCells that are misbehaving. It seems to be something with the image loading library and/or Xcode

Comment: I'll probably have to look at the code to pinpoint the issue

Comment: Apparently, it's got something to do with the cornerRadius of the UIImageView. I was setting the cornerRadius to be half of the height of the UIImageView. Just tried giving it an absolute value and all the UIImageViews started showing up

Answer (score 0):

Use this is in your code when all the data in tableView is loaded successfully

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
```

Comment: I am doing that @iOS Geek. Everything gets loaded except for the images.

Comment: can you please show the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath here ?

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this, for now, is -

I was giving my `UIImageView`s a value relative to its height in the following manner -

```
    cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.userImage.frame.size.height / 2;
```

Changed it to -

```
    cell.userImage.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0f;
```

And it's working just fine. Not sure where the issue is but I am assuming that it's got something to with the storyboard/constraints in the Xcode 9.0 beta.